# TCP/UDP packets not reaching docker container

Tags: linux, networking, docker

My host machine OS is OEL7 with kernel

`Linux ispaaaems1 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jul 9 18:59:11 PDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

And my `docker info` is

```
Containers: 4

Images: 124

Storage Driver: devicemapper

 Pool Name: docker-253:0-88356-pool

 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB

 Backing Filesystem: xfs

 Data file:

 Metadata file:

 Data Space Used: 7.43 GB

 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB

 Data Space Available: 99.94 GB

 Metadata Space Used: 9.302 MB

 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB

 Metadata Space Available: 2.138 GB

 Udev Sync Supported: true

 Library Version: 1.02.107-RHEL7 (2015-12-01)

Execution Driver: native-0.2

Kernel Version: 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64

Operating System: Oracle Linux Server 7.2

CPUs: 2

Total Memory: 7.641 GiB

Name: ispaaaems1

ID: 6MUK:HS3D:OQTS:QMWY:WCKE:AZT6:COJP:F7EA:RPNX:7RHY:TKFB:D4LT
```

I am running a docker container with OS OEL6.6. I am sending a radius request at 1812-1813. All the packets are reaching the host machine, but few packets (3 out of 5) are getting dropped (not reaching inside the container).

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in adavance.